# Rate of change of oustanding consumer credit.

Tags: integration, derivatives

I am currently reviewing for my test , and one of my test review problems states following :

[image]

I cant understand 6A.. where it tells me to determine the value of A.. Im guessing she is asking for me to determine the lower bound, but how do i do that? Thanks.

The question states : The rate of change of outstanding consumer credit in the 1900's can be modeled by the function $c(x)=-6.0912x^2+64.2030x-56.2477$ billion dollars per year $x$ years since $1990$. A graph of c is shown in figure.

Comment: what does $A$ refer to?

Comment: @SlugPue when we did our examples she mainly refered $A$ As the lower bound.. but im not 100% Sure for this test review question.

Comment: lower bound for what? I have to say it's quite absurd it is not stated in the problem what $A$ actually is.

Comment: @SlugPue lower bound for the accumulated area. there is higher bound and lower bound discussed in integration. Yes I will ask why A wasn't explicitly told what it is, but im guessing its the lower bound.

Comment: it seems that in b and c you have to integrate between $A$ and something else, so I assume $A$ is some number along the $x$ axis. Maybe its the $x$-value where $c(x) = 0$. But I don't really know. Basically, it's a badly posed problem by your teacher.